# is there a possibility to release a Kotlin multiplatform app for android and as a progressive web app?

Tags: android, kotlin, progressive-web-apps, kotlin-multiplatform

I would like to develop an app in kotlin that I can eventually publish as an apk in the playstore and also publish as a progressive web app to cover the ios market (and others). Is this possible with the help of kotlin multiplatform or not?

I've seen some hints on the kotlin site that this should be possible or is coming. But I can't find any practical hints on how this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin Multiplatform can target the web with Kotlin/JS so yes you can write a PWA with Kotlin/JS and KMP. You can use power of KMP to share business logic between the Kotlin/JS app and other targets (e.g. Android and iOS) if you'd like.
After a quick internet search, this could be a useful resource: [KotlinConf 2019: Building Progressive Web Apps in Kotlin by Erik Hellman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AhTzpIQJTw)